# Unable to call function inside context hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm currently trying to setup an authentication component which contains the react context API.
Everything is working correct except the fact that I'm unable to call a method from the context hook and I don't get what is going wrong.

```
// authContext.ts
export const AuthContext = createContext({
    authenticated: false,
    user: {
        role: ""
    },
    accessToken: "",
    initiateLogin: () => {},
    handleAuthentication: () => {},
    logout: () => {}
})
```

```
// Auth.tsx
const Auth: FunctionComponent = (props) => {
    const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false)
    const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState('')
    const [user, setUser] = useState({ role: "user" })

    const auth = new auth0.WebAuth({
        domain: AUTH_CONFIG.domain,
        clientID: AUTH_CONFIG.clientId,
        redirectUri: AUTH_CONFIG.callbackUrl,
        audience: `https://${AUTH_CONFIG.domain}/userinfo`,
        responseType: "token id_token"
    })

    function initiateLogin () {
        auth.authorize()
    }

    function logout() {
        setAuthenticated(false)
        setUser({ role: "user" })
        setAccessToken('')
    }

    function handleAuthentication() {
        auth.parseHash((error, authResult) => {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error)
                return
            }

            if (authResult == null) {
                return
            }

            setSession(authResult.idTokenPayload)
        })
    }

    function setSession(data: any) {
        const user = {
            id: data.sub,
            email: data.email,
            role: data[AUTH_CONFIG.roleUrl]
        }
        setUser(user)
        setAccessToken(data.accessToken)
        setAuthenticated(true)
    }

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{authenticated, accessToken, user, initiateLogin, handleAuthentication, logout}}>
            <AbilityContext.Provider value={buildAbilityFor(user.role)}>
                {props.children}
            </AbilityContext.Provider>
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export { Auth }
```

```
// Dashboard.tsx
function Dashboard() {

    const authentication = useContext(AuthContext)

    function login() {
        authentication.initiateLogin()
    }

    return (
        <Auth>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/callback' component={Callback} />
            </Switch>

            <Button onClick={login}>Login</Button>
        </Auth>
    )
}

export { Dashboard }
```

I'm trying to call the `initiateLogin` method from the Dashboard and the method is not getting called from the used context. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is `login()` being executed? You declare that function but do not call it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the context to be usable inside `Dashboard`, you need to wrap the provider around this component. In your example, you have your provider inside `Auth`, so need to wrap `Auth` around `Dashboard`:

```
<Auth>
  <Dashboard />
</Auth>
```

Also, you have just declared a `login` function without calling it. You also need to invoke it, i.e. in a `useEffect`, or on a button click.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot man!
Seems that the order was not correct what I didn't expect!